# Steam reviews to MySQL database

Tags: json, steam, steamworks-api

I'm trying to get all the reviews of a certain game from steam through this method: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/getreviews and dumb the data either in a MySQL DB or at least export it as an Excel spreadsheet. The structure of the db has to be exactly as the returns in the link above (author, review, etc) without the need for further customization.

I'm a total beginner when it comes to json, steamworks and the like so any links to in-depth tutorials regarding similar matters and explanations to any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found the following, which is actual pretty easy but since im an amateur i didnt know how to properly search for it. Heres the solution for any other amateurs out the:

I just copy and paste all my data in the following site: https://json-csv.com

In my case I had to copy/paste multiple parts since the Get List functions from steamworks only brings back batches of 20 reviews per time. (Keep in mind that you must insert this in the URL `&start_offset=0` then `&start_offset=20"` and so on to get all the reviews). You must also insert `&filter=recent` or `&filter=updated` or else it wont work.

Then i just download a csv file compatitle with excel and all my data structured and manipulatable any way i want.